# Detect the scrolling position of list view when little bit position changing(Without changing appearing item) also in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to find out the scroll view position of a list view, if we change the scrolling position little bit also. I have browse the net many solutions suggested that using 'ItemAppearing' event in list view but that event is not satisfying my requirement because that event fire only when item will be changed at the time of scrolling but In my list each item height is nearly equal to the my screen height that's for changing the item it takes large position of scrolling. Because of that after scrolling large position only that event will fired but what my requirement is just changing the little position of scrolling also need to detect that one. Please suggest any idea. Thanks in advance.